# К сделать на форме с помощью Fast Report встроенный предварительный просмотр?

Tags: delphi, fastreport

Как встроить в область моей формы TForm предварительный просмотр отчета?
Нахожу везде только примеры как запустить предварительный просмотр ( запускается как самостоятельное отдельное приложение).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для этого следует, влючить превью в форму, привязать ее к отчету, и запустить просмотр отчета.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin

  frxReport1.Preview := frxPreview1;
  frxReport1.ShowReport();

end;
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]